# Pronorm of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. The *pronormaliser* of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$, denoted  $P_G(H)$, is defined to be the set of elements of $G$ that pronormalise $H$. That is, $$P_G(H) = \{g \in G \; | \; \exists x\in \langle H, H^g \rangle\;\,\text{such that} \,\;H^x = H^g \}$$

From this we can define the *pronorm of G* as $$P(G) = \bigcap \limits_{H\in \Sigma} P_G(H)$$ where $\Sigma$ is the class of all subgroups of $G$.

**Lemma**: If $H$ is a subnormal subgroup of $G$, then $P_G(H) = N_G(H)$.

**Definition**: The Wielandt subgroup of $G$ is defined to be the intersection of all the normalisers of the subnormal subgroups of $G$ i.e. $$\omega(G) = \bigcap_{H \triangleleft \triangleleft G} N_G(H).$$

> Suppose that $P(G) \subseteq H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$. I need to show that $P(G) \subseteq \omega(H)$.

From the Lemma, $P(G) \subseteq P_G(K)=N_G(K)$ for each subnormal subgroup $K$ of $G$, and hence $P(G) \subseteq \omega(G)$. I can't seem to reason as to why $P(G) \subseteq \omega(H)$ would follow from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any subnormal subgroup $K$ of $H$, we have $P(G) \subseteq P_G(K) \cap H = P_H(K) = N_H(K)$, so $P(G) \subseteq \omega(H)$.